# Why are orthogonal matrices so often denoted $Q$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ho.history-overview, notation

I apologize for the stupid question in the title. Of course, we can baptize a particular given matrix as we want but, for example, the *QR-decomposition* has a fixed meaning.

My humble guess is that somebody had the idea to use $O$ for orthogonal Matrices and, since this clashes with $0$, then changed to $Q$.

To state an explicit Question: What is the first appearance in the literature of the term *QR decomposition*?

Comment: cf [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691537/history-question-qr-factorization), and the comment on one of the answers which is the same as your question.

Comment: Also: [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2016/10/03/householder-reflections-and-the-qr-decomposition/) it is claimed that  "The letter Q is a substitute for the letter O from "orthogonal" and the letter R is from "right", an alternative for "upper"." The author does not attribute any sources, however.

Comment: Not an answer: Also, in the 1940s K. Iwasawa looked at such decompositions $G=PK$ for more general semi-simple and reductive real Lie groups $G$, where $P$ is a minimal parabolic and $K$ is a maximal compact subgroup, and in some circles these are called "Iwasawa decompositions". From work of A. Borel, J. Tits,  and others c. 1960, similar decompositions are known for p-adic reductive groups as well (although there the characterization of the compact subgroup is no longer in terms of quadratic forms, etc.)

Comment: 1) Different title and body question is rarely a good idea; what qualifies as an answer? 2) QR decomposition (Francis 1961) seems a red herring; Gantmacher’s *Theory of matrices* ([1953](//zbmath.org/?q=an:0050.24804), [1959](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=107649)) already called orthogonal matrices $Q$ [throughout](//books.google.com/books?id=ePFtMw9v92sC&ots=sldmqJ4NId&pg=PA281&dq=orthogonal). 3) The shift you suggest from $O$ to $Q$ can be seen in Dickson’s *Linear groups* (1901, pp. 166, [169](//archive.org/details/lineargroupswith00dickuoft/page/169)–176, 179–185).

Answer (score 4):

The explanation that "*The letter Q is a substitute for the letter O from orthogonal* " may or may not be what [John Francis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_G._F._Francis) had in mind when he introduced [The QR Transformation: A Unitary Analogue to the LR Transformation](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article/4/3/265/380632) (1961), but the use of these two letters to indicate the decomposition of a matrix goes back further. Here is a [reference](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371687) by A.H. Clifford from 1942:

[image]

The fact that Q and R are subsequent letters in the alphabet makes this a natural combination, perhaps more natural than the O $\mapsto$ Q switch.

<sub>[Golub and Uhlig](https://www.math.unipd.it/~alvise/AN_2016/LETTURE/QR_50_years_later.pdf) suggest that Francis’s QR algorithm may have been influenced by Rutishauser’s qd algorithm, where "q" stands for "quotient". Since this lower case q refers to a vector rather than a matrix, it does not seem a likely explanation for the choice of the letter Q.</sub>

Comment: Francis always speaks of *unitary* matrices $Q$ instead of *orthogonal* -- it is thus not so plausible that he though of $Q$ is a replacement for $0$.